# How to make String to const wchar_t* conversion function work under Windows and Linux

Tags: gcc, wchar-t, c-str

I work on a project written for MSVCC / Windows, that I have to port to GCC / Linux. The Project has its own String Class, which stores its Data in a QString from Qt. For conversion to wchar_t* there was originally this method (for Windows):

```
const wchar_t* String::c_str() const
{
    if (length() > 0)
    {
        return (const wchar_t*)QString::unicode();
    }
    else
    {
        return &s_nullString;
    }
}
```

Because unicode() returns a QChar (which is 16 Bit long), this worked under Windows as wchar_t is 16 Bit there, but now with GCC wchar_t is 32 Bit long, so that doesn't work anymore. I've tried to solve that using this:

```
const wchar_t* String::c_str() const
{
    if ( isEmpty() )
    {
        return &s_nullString;
    }
    else
    {
        return toStdWString().c_str();
    }
}
```

The problem with this is, that the object doesn't live anymore when this function returns, so this doesn't work eiter.
I think the only way to solve this issue is to either:

1. Don't use String::c_str() and call .toStdString().c_str() directly
2. Make GCC treat wchar_t as 16 bit type

Possibility one would mean several hours of needless work to me and I don't know if possiblity 2 is even possible. My question is, how do I solve this issue best?
I'd appreciate any useful suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, there are 2 ways :

1. convert QString to wchar_t* when needed
2. Let QString to store wchar_t* and return QString::unicode directly

These two functions can convert a QString to std::string and std::wstring
[QString::toStdWString](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qstring.html#toStdWString)
[QString::toStdString](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qstring.html#toStdString)

To build QString as ucs4 :

```
#define QT_QSTRING_UCS_4
#include "qstring.h"
```

This can be used in qt3([qstring.h](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qstring-h.html)). I can't find the source of qt4.

Comment: Converting QString to wchar_t* when needed means calling .toStdString().c_str() directly. As I said before, this would be a lot of work and my last option, although that would be the optimal way to solve this. If i understood you right, you mean I should alternatively make Qt return a 32bit wchar, when calling unicode() by adding this #define. This solution sounds good to me. I'll test that.

Comment: when needed means : we should manage `the lifetime of intermediate object`(string,wstring) very carefully... otherwise, accessing of invalid object or memory leak.Could we put wstring as a member of String class?And update wstring when String::c_str() is called ?

Comment: Thank you. Adding a wstring member to the String class and update it when String::c_str() is called solved my problem. :)